# Deedle, multiplying columns of a frame by scalar values

Tags: f#, deedle

Suppose you have a dictionary of weights that need to by multiplied by the respective column of a deedle frame. In python it would be something like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((3,3)),columns=list("abc"))
>>> d = {"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}
>>> df * pd.Series(d)
     a    b    c
0  1.0  2.0  3.0
1  1.0  2.0  3.0
2  1.0  2.0  3.0
```

How to go about this in Deedle?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can make it in three lines but definitely not as succint as pandas:

```
let df = Array2D.create 3 3 1. |> Frame.ofArray2D |> Frame.indexColsWith("abc" |> Seq.toArray)
let multi = dict ['a',1.;'b',2.;'c',3.;] 
df |> Frame.getNumericCols |> Series.map (fun idx v -> multi.[idx] * v) |> Frame.ofColumns
```

Note that I'm creating a sequence of chars from the string array, hence the `'a'`.

I vaguely recall that the operators maybe overloaded to work on the dataframe in pandas. You can do the same thing with deedle as well. So you can say `df * df'`, where `df'` contains your scalars to multiply with.

**Something like this:**

```
let df' = Array2D.init 3 3 (fun i j -> float j + 1.) |> Frame.ofArray2D |> Frame.indexColsWith("abc" |> Seq.toArray)
df * df'
```